# Umbraco 7 RTE Paste from word?

Tags: umbraco, rich-text-editor, rte, umbraco7

I cannot see the option in the Rich Text Editor anymore for pasting from word. The strip formatting isn't enough as it leaves heading tags etc. I just want to have all HTML stripped when pasting. Does anyone know a way round this, I'd prefer not to end up offering Markdown as my only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the file /config/tinymceconfig.config

According to [this page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:paste_word_valid_elements) on the tinyMce documentation you should add the elements which you want to keep :

```
paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2"
```

So if you add this to the `customConfig` section if the file above, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for your response it has helped me investigate further. In the location you suggested in Umbraco there is a xml file that takes commands, I basically need the XML command for the copy from word. Been googling and have thus far come up fruitless. Will post when I find or will be very happy if someone knows of finds first : )